# Run App with Wear app without watch

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I want to make an app with optional wear app.

If device has a paired watch, so install app on watch. But if not, the app mobile should works withou a wear.

I created a project on Android Studio and select to create a mobile and wear app, but when the project is executed throw a error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find wearable shared library classes. Please add <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable" android:required="false" /> to the application manifest
    at android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity.initAmbientSupport(WearableActivity.java:187)
    at android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity.onCreate(WearableActivity.java:70)
    at com.mundocompilado.sesamo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

So, how can I make a app with option wear works?

Obs: I have two projects: mobile and wear

Mobile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mundocompilado.sesamo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Wear:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mundocompilado.sesamo">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any helps?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. In left of button "Run" in android studio has a selectable module, by default mine project was selected wear. So I changed to mobile project and works well.

Answer (score 0):

Wear:

gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.0'
    }
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />//optional
```

Mobile Application:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.2.0'
 wearApp project(':wear')

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

How to connect device with wear simulator

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

Comment: Not work, when I debug in my device without a wear the same error show. I want the app wear be optional, if the device not have a wear bounded the mobile module execute alone, without wear module.